# Pull certain Wordpress posts on custom CMS instead and 301 wordpress to it?

Tags: customization

Say a site has its main custom CMS on www. and a wordpress blog on blog. Up to now some really good reviews have been posted over years on blog. but believe now they would be best served on www. Is there a way to pull this content in all its glory and still use WP to power it behind the scenes but display on the www? Not only that but then have a 301 setup to move them all across and no longer show on the blog. subdomain?

Appreciate anyone who could point me in the best direction to do this if its possible. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are moving content permanently to the CMS I would advise to actually **move** it, rather than fiddle with integration. Not worth the trouble for static move.

As for redirect it is common use case and I would do some digging at [`redirect` tag at official plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/redirect).

Comment: The only thing is the handling of the imagery etc. In the posts will be imagery which is hosted on the blog and formatted out etc nicely. To move it across to our product CMS would mean effectively building something akin to Wordpress post editing to deal with that. Thanks for the redirect stuff and appreciate the answer.

Comment: @Jimbo you would like have plenty of formatting issues with pulling content from elsewhere just as well... That's why I'd just do it once. And maybe just make originals private in case year down the road someone decides everything needs to be moved back. :)

Comment: thanks for the reply :-) I guess I need to think this through ALOT! Its certainly not sounding a straight forward choice nor implementation. If it was WP still powering it then it would be possible to still make changes etc. Wondering if even pulling in a custom RSS only open to the main site with full article would even work. Guess I need to do some testing and then make a decision based on bit more data.